# gulp.js sub task compiling bad js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

front end developer is on holidays and I need to make a few changes quickly.

I am running a gulp subtask to merge js files into a single app.js. When I run this subtask just to watch for changes it compiles a new app.js file that is completely different from the server file even though I did not make any changes. The website does not load if I run this subtask even with no changes.

I get an error

```
TypeError: selector cannot be an empty string
```

Here is the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    bundle();
}); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
      // log errors if they happen
      .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
      .pipe(source('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
      .pipe(livereload());
```

Time is running out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Task runner in vs. It was set up for command line.